# Java adding a double quote to my string

Tags: java, string, quotes

I created a class with  3 Strings .

*code part 1:*

```
public static final String GET_BY_QUALIFICATION_PRODUIT = " INNER JOIN rel_qualifications_produit ON rel_qualifications_produit.idqualifications = qualifications.idqualifications WHERE rel_qualifications_produit.idproduit = ? order by order asc";
```

and i used test attribute in another method .

*code part 2:*

```
String s = search + QualificationSQL.GET_BY_QUALIFICATION_PRODUIT;
statement = connection.prepareStatement(s);'
```

the problem is that *test* displays `""order by test asc""` and not `"order by test asc"` .

thanks for helping .

Comment: Please post the hole code and use proper formatting.

Comment: i didn't get your actual issue. can you be more specific. btw, you can add `"` character in a java string by giving `\"`

Comment: i want the final String to be like this {Select * From table order by column asc }.but when i concatenate it give me this result {Select * From table "order by column asc"}

Answer (score 2):

You can remove double quote characters from your `String` using `replaceAll("\"", "");`

Comment: yes that's right i can use this solution, but i want to know why it did it so i can escape it in the future

Comment: ok thank you for you're concern :) i will find why it did it .

Comment: and if i find the solution i will post it